# How to find server response time in client side javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, client-side, response-time

I'm building an content delivery application that has a sole focus on speed / response time, I want to find a way to test response time in comparison to my direct competitor. Is there a way to test a servers response time in client side JavaScript? All help is beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

I had to calculate the same when trying to reverse engineer the [Google Analytics timing](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#timing) hits. The solution was to make use of the [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API):

```
var serverResponseTime = window.performance.timing.responseStart - window.performance.timing.fetchStart;
```

The above JS gives the server response time in ms. This helped me out, so hopefully it's what you're looking for too.

Answer (score -1):

var sendDate = (new Date()).getTime();

$.ajax({

```
//type: "GET", //with response body

type: "HEAD", //only headers

url: "/someurl.htm",

success: function(){

    var receiveDate = (new Date()).getTime();

    var responseTimeMs = receiveDate - sendDate;

}});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.